# Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 2

Tags: banco-de-dados, mysql

Boa noite,

Estou fazendo um tabela no MySQL Workbench onde mostra dados de um departamento de contas a receber, porém estou tendo um problema quando eu vou inserir os valores ele dá o erro 1136 e eu já revi várias vezes tentando procurar algum erro de sintaxe ou se a quantidade de colunas e valores não batiam mesmo, mas pelo que eu vi está tudo certo.

Segue parte do código onde eu inseri os valores:

```
insert into departamento (NOME, NUMERO, VALOR, VENCIMENTO, BANCO) values 
('ABC PAPELARIA', '100100', '5000', '2017-01-20', 'ITAU'),
('LIVRARIA FERNANDES', '100110', '2500', '2017-01-22' 'ITAU'),
('LIVRARIA FERNANDES', '100120', '1500', '2016-10-15', 'BRADESCO'),
('ABC PAPELARIA', '100130', '8000', '2016-10-15', 'SANTADER'),
('LER E SABER', '200120', '10500', '2018-04-26', 'BANCO DO BRASIL'),
('LIVROS E CIA', '200125', '2000', '2018-04-26', 'BANCO DO BRASIL'),
('LER E SABER', '200130', '11000', '2018-09-26', 'ITAU'),
('PAPELARIA SILVA', '250350', '1500', '2018-01-26', 'BRADESCO'),
('LIVROS MM', '250360', '500', '2018-12-18', 'SANTADER'),
('LIVROS MM', '250370', '3400', '2018-04-26', 'SANTADER'),
('PAPELARIA SILVA', '250380', '3500', '2018-04-26', 'BANCO DO BRASIL'),
('LIVROS E CIA', '453360', '1500', '2018-06-15', 'ITAU'),
('LIVRO MM', '453365', '5400', '2018-06-15', 'BRADESCO'),
('PAPELARIA SILVA', '453370', '2350', '2017-12-27', 'ITAU'),
('LIVROS E CIA', '453380', '1550', '2017-12-27', 'BANCO DO BRASIL'),
('ABC PAPELARIA', '980130', '4000', '2016-12-11', 'ITAU'),
('LIVRARIA FERNANDES', '770710', '2500', '2016-11-15', 'SANTADER'),
('ABC PAPELARIA', '985001', '3000', '2016-09-11', 'ITAU'),
('PAPEL E AFINS', '985002', '2500', '2016-03-12', 'SANTADER'),
('LER E SABER', '888132', '2500', '2017-03-05', 'ITAU');
```

Comment: Os danos que uma vírgula a menos não causa, hein ? Mas se vc perceber, na mensagem de erro explica que o erro era na linha 2 (row 2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creio que o erro esteja na terceira linha:

```bsh
('LIVRARIA FERNANDES', '100110', '2500', '2017-01-22' 'ITAU'),
```

faltou uma vírgula antes de `'ITAU'`:

```sql
insert into departamento (NOME, NUMERO, VALOR, VENCIMENTO, BANCO) values 
('ABC PAPELARIA', '100100', '5000', '2017-01-20', 'ITAU'),
-- ('LIVRARIA FERNANDES', '100110', '2500', '2017-01-22' 'ITAU'),<- Faltou uma virgula
('LIVRARIA FERNANDES', '100110', '2500', '2017-01-22', 'ITAU'),
('LIVRARIA FERNANDES', '100120', '1500', '2016-10-15', 'BRADESCO'),
('ABC PAPELARIA', '100130', '8000', '2016-10-15', 'SANTADER'),
('LER E SABER', '200120', '10500', '2018-04-26', 'BANCO DO BRASIL'),
('LIVROS E CIA', '200125', '2000', '2018-04-26', 'BANCO DO BRASIL'),
('LER E SABER', '200130', '11000', '2018-09-26', 'ITAU'),
('PAPELARIA SILVA', '250350', '1500', '2018-01-26', 'BRADESCO'),
('LIVROS MM', '250360', '500', '2018-12-18', 'SANTADER'),
('LIVROS MM', '250370', '3400', '2018-04-26', 'SANTADER'),
('PAPELARIA SILVA', '250380', '3500', '2018-04-26', 'BANCO DO BRASIL'),
('LIVROS E CIA', '453360', '1500', '2018-06-15', 'ITAU'),
('LIVRO MM', '453365', '5400', '2018-06-15', 'BRADESCO'),
('PAPELARIA SILVA', '453370', '2350', '2017-12-27', 'ITAU'),
('LIVROS E CIA', '453380', '1550', '2017-12-27', 'BANCO DO BRASIL'),
('ABC PAPELARIA', '980130', '4000', '2016-12-11', 'ITAU'),
('LIVRARIA FERNANDES', '770710', '2500', '2016-11-15', 'SANTADER'),
('ABC PAPELARIA', '985001', '3000', '2016-09-11', 'ITAU'),
('PAPEL E AFINS', '985002', '2500', '2016-03-12', 'SANTADER'),
('LER E SABER', '888132', '2500', '2017-03-05', 'ITAU');
```

Comment: Vamos ver. Esperando a guria confirmar pra dar o seu "like". Rs

Comment: Muito obrigada! Agora deu certo, não tinha notado mesmo que estava faltando essa vírgula.